# Generic $_GET validator

Tags: php

I want a dead simple generic $_GET-vars validator, and don't have any desire to reinvent the wheel.

Is there any solid and simple script I can use, something like:

```
function secure($varName,$format = 'int') {
//format: boolean,int,dec,str,date
    //add stripslashes if mq
    $var = $_GET[$varName];
switch($format) {
  case 'int':
    $r = floor($var);
    break;
  case 'boolean':
    $r = ($var === true);
    break;
  case 'dec':
    $r = preg_replace("/0-9.-/i", "", $val);
    break;
  case 'str':
    ..
  case 'date':
    //ISO 8601 is enough...
}
```

regards,
//t

Comment: I don't understnad what you mean by "generic validator" and how does PDO play into this? Validation for what? What is your final goal?

Comment: Hi, Pekka, sorry for incorrect title, please reload. use as in FOSS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`filter_input()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) comes fairly close to what you want to do.

It's got a decent number of [validation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) and [sanitation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) filters.

An example stolen from the manual:

```
<?php
var_dump(filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
var_dump(filter_var('http://example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, 
                                          FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED));
?>
```

Comment: Be it known that it does not validate emails with a top-level-domain, so `bob@example` will not return false.

Comment: Great Pekka, good stuff. Though I miss time, date and timestamp.

Comment: @Levi well, that's *technically* correct.... IMO,  E-Mail address validation is pointless anyway - the only way to make sure an E-Mail address exists, is sending a mail to it and waiting for the recipient to click the confirmation link.

Comment: @Pekka I should have mentioned it earlier, but see http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585 for improved email validation, including domain checking.  This makes sure the email is formatted correctly, preventing errors for scripts later on.

Comment: @user fair points. You could create your own custom filters for that using the `callback` type - you'd still have to write it by yourself but it would be under the roof of a standard function.

Comment: @Levi interesting, thanks. Although I really tend to accept anything matching `*@*` and send a confirmation E-Mail (but doing *some* filtering will keep some of the obvious typos out, that's true.)

Comment: since OP asked for `$_GET` the more appropriate filter would be `filter_input`

Comment: would date('Y-m-d', strtotime($var)) be the prefered solution?

Comment: @user you mean for a date? Hmm, that would accept a *lot*. Including `last tuesday` and `+5 day`. I guess it depends on whether that's okay for you or not

Comment: @Gordon and @Pekka, it's still false, the type is not `filter_input()`, but rather `filter_input_array()`, as I have suggested. `filter_input` applies to a certain variable, *_array will filter the whole thing based on configurations.

Comment: @Levi well, if you take the OP's request *literally* looking at the code he provides, he wants `filter_input()`. But I agree that if you want to sanitize your whole GET array in one go, `filter_input_array()` is the way to go. (Hence +1 from me for you)

Comment: @levi, what's false? I see the advantages of filter_input_array, but I *want* to apply the filters in "runtime".

Answer (score 2):

Pekka gave a great function I didn't know about, but `filter_input_array` is what you actually want.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php

Example:

**Edit:** Now shows how to validate a DateTime (ie, a timestamp).

```
/* data that came from GET
$_GET = array(
    'id'    => '14',
    'name' => 'Guidoe'
    'archived' => 'on',
    'date' => '2006-12-12 10:00:00'
);
*/

$args = array(
    'id'   => array('filter'    => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                            'options'   => array('min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 1000)
                           ),
    'archived'     => array('filter'    => FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN,
                            'flags'     => FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE
                           ),
    'date' => array('filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK,
                    'options' => 'valid_date_time'
                           )
    'name' =>array('filter'=>FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                   'flags'=>FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH
                           )

);

function valid_date_time($string) {
    $parsed = date_parse($string);
    if($parsed['error_count']>0 || $parsed['warning_count']>0)
        return false;

    return new DateTime($string);
}

$myinputs = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, $args);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I believe var_filter suits better for my purpose.

Comment: @user this is a shortcut to `filter_var()` that is pretty ideal if you want to sanitize all GET variables in one go.

Comment: @Pekka It is NOT a shortcut to filter_var(), rather it is the PHP defined way to filter an entire INPUT array.  You are not quite correct in that it doesn't sanitize all variables, only the ones specified in args.

Comment: @Levi I'm speculating it *is* a shortcut to filter_var in the end - the `INPUT_GET` part is just syntactic sugar. I don't know for sure,  but I'm willing to bet a large beer that it all ends up being processed by `filter_var()` internally.  What I meant by sanitizing all GET variables is of course that you specify every one in `$args`  - but this is what you want to use if you're looking to sanitize the whole lot of them

Comment: Yes, in that sense, it does apply `filter_var()`.  However, the mere existence of this function shows that the PHP dev team thinks it's a valid use-case that should have its own name.  I honestly would suspect that internally `filter_input_array(INPUT_GET,$args)` is exactly defined as `filter_var_array($_GET,$args)`.

Comment: it isnt: http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/filter/filter.c#831 :) /cc @Pekka

Comment: @Gordon Thanks for the link.  It does appear that they do use the same code `php_filter_array_handler`, which is the essence of what I meant.